# Is it possible to use Paypal payment from Paybox Direct?

Tags: paypal, payment

I have implemented my `Paybox Direct` with visa and master card, but I want one more payment method with `Papal`.

I can't find any document about this. So is it possible or not? and if it's possible, how to implement it OR any document to do it?